# Can't get area lighting to show on viewport or render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, light, scene

I can't seem to get the area light to be shining onto the deer head object.

As you can see it is there on the viewport and editable but no light is being emitted from the light.

Is there some setting that toggles the view of lighting in the viewport and render?.

As it doesn't appear in the render either. As you can see from these examples
[image]

[image]

Comment: no light is supposed to be displayed on the surface of the area itself if this is what you're looking for

Comment: I mean on the viewport it clearly shows the HDRI image as environment lighting but it doesnt show the green area light. I would like it to add a green glow to the targeted area but it doesnt show up at all.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sent, should work for you.

Comment: you need to copy paste the link it gives you  ;)

Comment: There it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=G4jokQQY" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/G4jokQQY/)

Comment: Use the tools from the site to make the images visible as part of the question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Is this the same question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200015/cant-get-green-area-lighting-to-show-on-viewport-or-render

Answer (score 1):

Give specularity to your area and it will work fine, even though its power is a bit weak:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow you are a lifesaver thanks! works great